# Am I not escaping this JavaScript HTML correctly?

Tags: javascript, escaping

Why is this JavaScript not getting rendered correctly when outputted as HTML?

```
var innerHtml = 
"<div style='color:yellow;font: 14px//14px /'Lucida Grande/',sans-serif;'>";
```

Am I not escaping something correctly?

Answer (score 4):

`/` should be `\`

```
var innerHtml = 
"<div style=\"color:yellow;font: 14px/14px 'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;\">"
```

Comment: -1 You really weren't looking at what he was setting. `font` uses `font-size/line-height`, no backslashes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape forward slashes (`/`), nor do you need to escape single quotes (`'`) (as you're quoting with double quotes `"`). The backslash is the escape character (`\`)

```
var innerHTML = '<div style="color:yellow; font: 14px/14px &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, sans-serif;">';
```

should work. I used single quotes as I prefer to have HTML output use double quotes (not that it matters in JavaScript, but it's a consistency thing).

Edit to HTML escape the font-family quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't the `font-face` quotes be escaped since the same type of quotes are used for the entire `style` declaration?

Comment: @Sean Vieira yes, you are right I forgot to HTML encode the quotes.